# Angular Azure B2C SSO issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

Context:
I have an MVC application, which uses OWIN, and connects to Azure for authentication. It stores a token in the cookie.

I have another application that is an angular spa application. This also connects to Azure for authentication. It stores the token in localstorage. (msal library)

Issue:
When I login to the MVC app first and open the spa app and click on login it again asks for credentials and vice versa.
This is due to different storage I believe.

Question :
How can the above issue be resolved? If it's not possible, 
is there any other js library that will allow me to solve this?

Other inputs:
Msal silent token works on local storage, no issue on that.

Comment: Are you saying that the SSO is not working between your angular SPA application and your MVC application, even though they are both registered in the same AAD b2c tenant?

Comment: yes, sorry for late response. I have resolved it with another library(other than MSAL). but still want to know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you register both applications under your B2C tenant. You can test your storage theory easily by publishing another MVC application and seeing if the SSO works between that application and your existing one.

Whether it's a single page angular application or an MVC application shouldn't affect whether the user can SSO into both of them. Ensure that the user is added in your AAD and if you want to be on the safe side you can add the user manually to both application.

Please see this relevant Github repository. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular2-4-spa/